# Italize subset of text in label of a checkbox lightning component

Tags: css, html5

I want to italicize part of the text in a checkbox label.  I am not finding a way to do this.  For example, I want the checkbox label to say *Biologics* technical workshop.  Only the word Biologics should be italicized in the label.

```
                                <lightning:input 
                                             name="workshopCheckbox" 
                                             aura:id="workshopCheckbox" 
                                             label="{!v.workshopTitle}" 
                                             type="checkbox" 
                                             checked="{!v.workshopCheckbox}" 
                                             />
```

Also need this for radio select

```
                                <p class="required">*</p>Please select a Registration Option:
                                <lightning:radioGroup aura:id="amountDueRadioButton" 
                                                  label=""
                                                  name="registrationOption"

                                                  onchange="{!c.calculateRegistrationAmountDue}"                       
                                                  type="radio"
                                                  options="{! v.registrationOptions }"
                                                  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the label is a string type attribute. Its value can not contain html tag like italic.

instead, you can change the variant to `label-hidden` and then add a label tag

Sample Code

**Html**

```
<lightning:input class="inline"
                 name="workshopCheckbox" 
                 aura:id="workshopCheckbox" 
                 checked="{!v.myValue}"
                 variant="label-hidden"
                 type="checkbox">

</lightning:input>
<label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="checkbox-unique-id-72">
    <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
    <span class="slds-form-element__label"><i>Biologics</i> technical workshop</span>
</label>
```

**Css**

```
.THIS .inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That worked for my checkbox label.  Thank you!  I also need to have italics in part of a label on radio button options.  I am updating my question to show that too.